# Number shows 1e+06 instead of 1 000 000

Tags: android, textview, numbers, size

im need to show some numbers in the textviews, but they when they have 6 or more digits, they appear like 1e+06 instead of 1 000 000.

I have to create the textviews dinamically, which i am able to do, and everything is working fine. Its just that that thing is not displaying as i would like to. I cant find a property in the textview that can avoid that type of number display.

Does it has to do with the size of the text view?

This is the code on java that im using to create them.

```
descrip=new TextView(context);

descrip.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);

descrip.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

descrip.setTextAlignment(Gravity.CENTER);

scrip.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Description")));

descrip.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

descrip.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

descrip.setBackground(img);

layDescrip.addView(descrip);
```

how can i make them to display the number as they would do usually?

thank you very much for your time

Comment: Are you sure it isn't stored that way? Coz Database stores strings and you are getting a string here. It might be that its getting stored in exponential form.

Comment: Print it to the Logcat to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: Yeah guys, you were totatlly right. That is the way that 6 or more digit numbers are getting stored. But Integer.Parsing them, or Double parsing them did the trick!  Thank you guys!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
scrip.setText(Integer.toString(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Description"))));
```

Comment: That did it!  :)   I actually used Integer.parseInt and got it. Hehe Thank you! You gave me the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this simply by using class `java.math.BigDecimal`. You can use `BigDecimal.valueOf()` to convert the Double value to `BigDecimal` and than `.toPlainString()` to convert it into plain decimal string.

```
double val = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Description"));
scrip.setText(BigDecimal.valueOf(val).toPlainString());
```

Source: [How to Convert Exponential Form of a number to Decimal Form in java](http://developers-arena.blogspot.ca/2011/03/how-to-convert-exponential-form-of.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! Ill keep in mind for a similar operation. Thanks again!  :)